How to trace a cassandra query by using preparedstatement QueryBuilder?
I'm trying to trace a query by using QueryBuilder and preparedStatement in cassandra using java.
preparedStatement = new SimplePreparedStatementCreator(String.valueOf(QueryBuilder.selectFrom(Student).columns(SELECT_FIELDS.whereColumn(Marks).isEqualTo(QueryBuilder.bindMarker(Marks)))).createPreparedStatement(session);

How can I enable tracing for this query using preparedStatement ? Can anyone please suggest me out for the same ?

Ensure that your project includes the required dependencies for your Java Cassandra driver to access the necessary classes and methods demonstrated above. Additionally, verify that query tracing is enabled on your Cassandra cluster at the server level. Please note that the method for enabling tracing may vary if you're using a different Java Cassandra driver than the one assumed in this example
// Enable query tracing
session.getContext().setTracing(true);
// Your prepared statement creation
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.prepare("Your CQL query here");
// Execute the query
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(/* Bind parameters here */);
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement);
// Optionally, retrieve and print the tracing information
if (session.getContext().getTracingSession() != null) {
String traceId = session.getContext().getTracingSession().getTraceId().toString();
System.out.println("Trace ID: " + traceId);
// Optionally, you can retrieve and print additional tracing information like events
}

Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm using cassandra starter 3.10 . I could not find option for setTracing method in a session. Can't we enable tracing on server via query builder from application ?

Can I enableTracing in the BoundStatement  ?  BoundStatement findByMarksy(Long number) {
return preparedStatement.bind(number)            .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM).setIdempotent(true).setTracing(true);
}

